# Error publishing Docker image to Azure container registry

Tags: docker, azure-container-registry

I am trying to publish my first Docker image (built from a simple .Net core console app) to my Azure container registry. The process started and ran for about two minues before errored out. Here is the error:

[image]

The log mentioned contains the same imformation.
It looks like the error is related to some Nuget package:

[image]

But the problem is that I don't have this "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.408" folder on my machine:

[image]

and I don't have a reference to that package in my project:

[image]

What am I missing? and what should do to fix it? I am totaly new to Docker so any inputs will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here is my firewall settings - it doesn't have any Docker related items in it! Could that be the problem? If so, how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are you connected to the internet when you ran the build? That error looks like it can't find that API URL.

Comment: I just verified my internet connection and retried the publish - same result.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would advise you to please **check the installation of the latest version of the ‘Docker Desktop for Windows’ software that is supported by ‘ASP .Net Core Web App’ long term release version**. It should be **compatible to the created ‘.Net Core Web App’ version such that when you are trying to publish your web app image from the Visual Studio App to the Azure container registry, the ‘Docker Desktop for Windows’ will be able to sync push the image to the linked ACR**.

•   Would also suggest you to **please check whether the Linux kernel package for x64 machines is updated or not. If not, would suggest you to please download the WSL2 Linux Kernel update package, install it and restart the ‘Docker Desktop for Windows’ software on your system**. This will ensure that the Linux kernel set for the Web app in Visual studio is accordingly setup in ‘Docker Desktop for Windows’ application.

•   Finally, please **check the local Windows firewall for the inbound allow rules for the ‘Docker Desktop for Windows’ software whether its backend is allowed to run and connect to the Azure Container Registry** or not as below: -

[image: Windows Firewall]

Also, **ensure that the ‘Azure.Container.ContainerRegistry’ library is installed in your environment through the Visual Studio extension gallery as it is required for developing a .Net Web app code. Please ensure that ‘Microsoft Authentication’ libraries are also installed correctly in your Visual Studio repository for successful connections**. I followed the below documentation link for publishing Docker image to Azure Container Registry and I was able to successfully connect to the ACR as shown below: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/hosting-web-apps-in-docker?view=vs-2022***

[image: ACR creation through VS]

Thus, would suggest you follow the given link.

Comment: Hi Kartik - thank you so much for your inputs! Your point about the firewall settings is especially important, as I don't have any of those settings as you do (see my updates above). Could that be my problem? How should I fix it?

Comment: Further investigation shows that the reason why my publish failed is because the "RUN dotnet restore ..." failed when trying to use NuGet to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. Therefore, the firewall thing sounds a lot like the possible cause of it.

Comment: Yes, on seeing the update from the image, I think that the prompt to bypass the communication with the public internet from this application in the firewall on private network should be allowed accordingly post which the publishing will be successful.

Comment: Could you be more specific abut how to do it please? How do I bypass the Internet conmunication? And how can I get to the NuGet source without Internet communication? I am not familar with these stuff at all, so please execuse my ignorence. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kindly refer to this link to bypass NuGet package sources through web application proxy or internet proxy server: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file, also to bypass the Docker backend service from the firewall, please allow it for all inbound private networks and ensure that you are connecting to the internet over VPN as well as specify this path and '.exe' in the inbound private rule : - 'C:\program files\docker\docker\resources\com.docker.backend.exe'

Comment: Thanks Kartik! Unfortunitlly, I don't have control over any of the security settings which are maintained by our IS group. I tried the same setup on a different machine and it works just fine without the issue. I don't know why, and I have decided to give up on my machine. I am ok now.